# AWS Amplify won't let me sign into the backend

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

In the terminal I executed this command:

`amplify pull --appId d2nb7sae2nlt33 --envName staging`

which gave me this response in the termina:

`Opening link: https://us-east-1.admin.amplifyapp.com/admin/d2nb7sae2nlt33/staging/verify/`
`Continue in browser to log in…`

In the browser, I'm asked to enter a username and password. I enter my aws root username and password, and I'm told they're incorrect. That username/password works everywhere else in AWS.

Am I supposed to set up some other user name/password for AWS Amplify?

Comment: It seems to want the "Admin UI" specific to Amplify?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in my case was:

1 You should be clear about which backend you are using. If you have two backends, then `d2nb7sae2nlt33` above may not refer to the backend where you have set up your credentials, and

2. No, the root user is not what you need to enter. The app needs to have an admin user set up. You set it up with a user, which sends an invite to an email, and you respond with a temp password, then set it up with a real password.

go to https://console.aws.amazon.co/amplify (there may be more, like the region, but that's the general idea)

then from the side menu go to Admin UI management under App Settings.

then Invite Users, big orange button in Access Control Settings.

This should get you on your way.

[image]

[image: the AWS Amplify sidebar]

Comment: `--apiId d2nb7sae2nlt33` is probably your [Appsync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) ID.  Although signing with browser works, I recommend to use `accessKeyId` & `secretAccessKey` to connect amplify CLI with your IAM user.

Comment: now is different, on the left menu `App settings -> Amplify Studio settings -> Access control settings -> Invite user`